# isnull argument not optional on form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

The following is the code i am trying to implement.  I want there to be a text box and check-mark on a form when a client is delinquent in their payments.  this is rare so i want it to only be visible when they are.  how ever im having trouble with it because when making a new job the form loads without the contact information and has no record to check for delinquency.  so i want it to check if there is a value to check then run whether it is delinquent or not.

```
If Me![Deliquent?] = IsNull Then
 Me.Check491.Visible = False
 Me.DeliquentLabel.Visible = False
 
Else

Me.Check491.Visible = (Me![Deliquent?] = True)
Me.DeliquentLabel.Visible = (Me![Deliquent?] = True)

End If
```

I am getting a "compile error arguement is not optional on the isnull in the first statement.  how do i fix this?

Comment: You can also use `If Me![Deliquent?] = Null Then ......`

Answer (score -1):

I am idiot i used the completely wrong syntax.  It should be

If isnull(me![delinquent?]) then...